# Play and pause sound with SpaceBar

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to play and pause a sound with JS.

The sound is already playing, but i want to be able to pause and unpause it.

```
case 32: //SpaceBar
  if (play){
    $("#leson").pause();
    play = false;
  } else {
    $("#leson").play();
    play = true;
  }
break;
```

And before i wrote this :

```
<embed id="leson" src="edito.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"
loop="false">
```

What am i doing wrong here ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change `embed` to HTML5 `audio`. And `autoplay` instead of `autostart`.
My solution doesn't uses jQuery.

See the code below and check it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/xNAtq/).
You need to click the result page to focus the page and be able to play/pause with spacebar.

```
<audio id="leson" src="edito.wav" autoplay="true" hidden="true" loop="false"/>
<script>
var play = true;

var myAudio = document.getElementById("leson");

function onKeyDown(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 32: //SpaceBar                    
                if (play) {
                    myAudio.pause();
                    play = false;
                } else {
                    myAudio.play();
                    play = true;
                }
                break;
        }
  return false;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`audio` elements have [`play` and `pause` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement#Methods).

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudioElement');
myAudio.play();
myAudio.pause();
```

And seeing you are using jQuery, you need to get the DOM element from the jQuery object. You should do:

```
$("#leson")[0].play();
$("#leson")[0].pause();
```

Comment: @ArthurPolui you are using `embed`